MTU - proactively setting to lower than 1500 on endpoints to prevent tunnel issues
With machines being deployed to various locations where internet is controlled by others, sometimes there can be one or two tunnels which necessitates using lower MTU to avoid communication issues, and this is not always known in advance.
Is the main drawback of proactively setting MTU to something like 1300 on the machines themselves (so as to cover all cases regardless of if needed or not) that it would add a tiny amount of slowdown to network communication and require more packets per second to be processed by network equipment for the same amount of data being sent?
I'm wondering if the drawbacks of doing this are negligible or if there is something significant I might be missing.

A big drawback is if you need to manually configure it on a bunch of devices. If you can set it via DHCP, that works pretty well, but statically configured devices my be done manually.

Yes, the main drawbacks are slightly decreased bandwidth efficiency, increased processing overhead and the likely need for a configuration method for statically configured nodes.
Bandwidth efficiency decreases due to less payload per packet. For TCP over IPv4 over Ethernet, it drops from 1460/1538 = 94.9% to 1260/1338 = 94.2%.
Likewise, processing overhead may increase by as much as 15% due to the increase of packets to process, depending on workloads.
MSS clamping on the gateway nodes may be a viable alternative to a general MTU decrease, but that works for TCP only and requires some more evaluation and testing.
